# Dry-Run Rubber (simulation)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, rubber

I would like to use Rubber for an app i'm making. Is there any way to do a dry-run of the same without actually creating instances on ec2?

Answer (score 0):

```
Byte x, y, z;
            x = 255;
            y = 3;
            z = (Byte)(x << y); Console.WriteLine(z);

            z = (Byte)(x >> y);
            Console.WriteLine(z);

            z = (byte)(x & y);
            
Console.WriteLine(z); z = (byte)(x | y); Console.WriteLine(z);

Boolean b = true;
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt16 (b));
```